# SQL WHERE Query brings back wrong values

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that is bringing back a list of results from our database. All of the select query is working apart from the last WHERE line. Even though the @ACTIVE variable is set to true the stored proc stills bring back results with GLEV_STATUS that = 1 , it should only bring back results that have GLEV_STATUS = 0. I imagine I have just written in the wrong syntax but I have tried many different combinations of where to put the brackects ect and still cant get it to only bring back results with GLEV_STATUS = 0 only.

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Outlook_Addin_Search]
    @SUBJECT varchar(50),
    @EVENTNO varchar(50),
    @CONTACT varchar(50),
    @ACTIVE varchar(50),
    @OwnerUserName varchar(200),
    @OwnerEmailName varchar(200),
    @OwnerEmail varchar(200)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @User varchar(100)

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Declare a return integer
    Declare @ReturnedCount as int;

    -- Find the User that is searching
    SET @User = (SELECT USER_SYS_NO FROM DB.f_ad_users WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE user_full_name = @OwnerUserName OR user_full_name = @OwnerEmailName OR user_email_address = @OwnerEmail OR user_log_name = @OwnerUserName OR user_log_name = @OwnerEmailName) 

    -- Call the new outlook count events function to find out how many possible records there are.
    set @ReturnedCount = [dbo].[fn_Outlook_CountEvents](@SUBJECT, @EVENTNO, @User, @CONTACT, @ACTIVE);

    -- Select DF Events Table
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 EVST_EVENT_TYPE
    , EVST_EDITABLE_BY
    , GLEV_SYS_NO
    , GLEV_USER_INIT
    , cast(GLEV_SUBJECT as varchar(MAX)) as GLEV_SUBJECT
    , cast(GLEV_NOTES as varchar(MAX)) as GLEV_NOTES
    , EVST_ALLOW_NOTE_EDITING
    , EVST_DEFAULT_TYPE
    , CONT_FIRST_NAME
    , CONT_SURNAME
    , GLEV_STATUS
    , @ReturnedCount as CountValue

    FROM DeFactoUser.F_GL_Events with (nolock)
    INNER JOIN DB.F_GL_Event_Status with(NOLOCK)
                ON GLEV_EVENT_TYPE = EVST_EVENT_TYPE
    LEFT JOIN DB.F_GL_Contacts with (NOLOCK)
                ON CONT_CONCAT = GLEV_CONTACT
    LEFT JOIN DB.F_GL_Event_Distribution with (NOLOCK)
                ON EVDN_GLEV_SYS_NO = GLEV_SYS_NO

    WHERE  (GLEV_SUBJECT like ('%' + @SUBJECT + '%')
        AND GLEV_SYS_NO like (@EVENTNO + '%'))
        AND (CONT_FIRST_NAME + CONT_SURNAME LIKE ('%' + @CONTACT + '%') OR (@CONTACT = '' AND CONT_FIRST_NAME IS NULL))
        AND ((EVST_DEFAULT_TYPE = 1) OR (EVST_DEFAULT_TYPE = 0 AND (GLEV_USER_INIT = @User OR EVDN_USER_SYS_NO = @User)) OR (EVST_DEFAULT_TYPE = 2 AND GLEV_USER_INIT = 8))
        AND ((EVST_EDITABLE_BY = 0) OR (EVST_EDITABLE_BY = 1 AND GLEV_USER_INIT = @User) OR (EVST_EDITABLE_BY = 2 AND EVDN_USER_SYS_NO = @User))
        AND ((@ACTIVE = 'false' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0 OR GLEV_STATUS = 1) OR (@ACTIVE = 'true' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0))
    ORDER BY GLEV_SYS_NO DESC


END
```

This line is the problem:

```
AND ((@ACTIVE = 'false' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0 OR GLEV_STATUS = 1) OR (@ACTIVE = 'true' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0))
```

Exec the SP with:

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_Outlook_Addin_Search]
        @SUBJECT = N'',
        @EVENTNO = N'',
        @CONTACT = N'',
        @ACTIVE = N'true',
        @OwnerUserName = N'Name',
        @OwnerEmailName = NULL,
        @OwnerEmail = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some brackets
Change

```
AND (
        (@ACTIVE = 'false' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0 OR GLEV_STATUS = 1)
        OR (@ACTIVE = 'true' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0)
    )
```

into

```
AND (
        (@ACTIVE = 'false' AND (GLEV_STATUS = 0 OR GLEV_STATUS = 1))
        OR (@ACTIVE = 'true' AND GLEV_STATUS = 0)
    )
```

The first one will return the row if active is false and status is 0, or it will return the row if glev status is 1.